# Как перехватить данные заказа в opencart?

Tags: opencart

Подскажите как в Opencart 2  проще всего получить данные после оформления заказа для отправки его на доставку через json запрос в другую систему (используется модуль simple).

Answer (score 0):

по крону запускается скрип, в котором из базы данных извлекаются заказы, таблицы oc_order_product и  oc_order.

```
select order_id,date_added,email,firstname, lastname, shipping_country,shipping_zone,shipping_code,payment_method,total ,shipping_city,shipping_address_1,shipping_postcode,telephone,comment from oc_order where (date_added BETWEEN '$last_time_update' AND '$cur_date') AND order_status_id=1

select name,quantity from oc_order_product where order_id='$order_id'
```